# Captcha image not showing

Tags: php, html, captcha

Ok...so...i'm trying the create my own Captcha to use on a webpage i'm working on.
Since i'm pretty much a noob on php i followed a youtube guide

i followed EVERY SINGLE STEP in this video, everything he did i did too, i dowloaded the same image lybrary(AnonymousClippings.tff btw) and etc BUT for some reason my captcha image is not showing.

I have to files, one for the captcha and one for the index(to call the image function so i can see the image) and use it in a form.

i'm sure the reason for not showing the image is pretty stupid but i just can't figure what's the problem.

if you know a easier way to create my own captcha i would apreciate.

captcha.php

```
<?php

class captcha{
private static $captcha = "__captcha__";
private static $font;
private static $width = 70;
private static $height = 70;
private static $font_size = 40;
private static $character_width = 40;

private static function session_start(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
}
private static function set_font(){
self::$font = self::$captcha;
$AnonymousClippings = "HERE GOES ALL POSSIBLE CAHRS THAT THE CAPTCHA WILL BE ABLE TO SHOW FROM AnonymousClippings LYBRARY";
$handle = fopen(self::$font,"w+");
fwrite($handle, base64_encode($AnonymousClippings));
fclose($handle);

return self::$font;
}
public static function get_random(){
$type = rand(0,2);

switch ($type){
    case 2:
        $random = chr(rand(65, 90));
        break;
    case 1:
        $random = chr(rand(97, 122));
        break;
    default:
        $random = chr(rand(0,9));
        break;

}
return $random;

}

private static function get_width(){
return self::$width;

}

private static function get_height(){
return self::$height;
}

private static function generate_code($length){
self::session_start();

$code=null;

for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
    $code.=self::get_random();
}
$_SESSION[self::$captcha] = $code;

self::$width = $length * self::$character_width;

return $code;

}

public static function image(){

$length = 6;
$code = self::generate_code($length);

self::set_font();
ob_start();

$image = imagecreatetruecolor(self::get_width(),self::get_height());
$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, self::get_width(), self::get_height(), $white);

for($dot=0;$dot<2000;$dot++){
    $red = rand(0,255);
    $green = rand(0,255);
    $blue = rand(0,255);

    $dot_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $red, $green, $blue);
            $x1 = rand(0,self::get_width());
            $y1= rand(0,self::get_height());
            $x2 = $x1 +1;
            $y2 = $y1 +1;
            imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $dot_color);

}

for($start = $length*(-1); $start<0; $start++){
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, rand(0,177), rand(0,177), rand(0,177));
    $character = substr($code, $start,1);

    $x =($start+6)*self::$character_width;
    $y = rand(self::get_height()-20, self::get_height() -10);

    imagettftext($image, self::$font_size, 0, $x, $y, $color, self::$font, $character);
}
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);

$source = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

unlink(self::$font);

return "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($source);

}

public static function get_code(){
self::session_start();
return $_SESSION[self::$captcha];

}



}


?>
```

index1.php

```
<?php

require_once("captcha.php");


if(isset($_POST["code"])){
    if($_POST["code"]== captcha::get_code()){
        echo "good";
    }else{
        echo "wrong";
    }
}


?>


<form method="post">
<img src=" <?php captcha::image() ?>"/><br>
<input type="text" name="code"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Check"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: NO, i just dosent show the image, even the form works(at least when its the wrong code)

Comment: I suggest to rewrite the class not  using static methods. It would be way cleaner to make an instance of a Captcha. (IMHO)

Comment: Errors are enabled ? `captcha::image()` no semi-colon ?

Comment: i acdentaly changed some methods into not-static methods but i got a ton of errors all around.

Comment: `src=" <?php capt` blankspace in src

Comment: yes, errors are enabled, i ahd a ton of then before, now that i corrected mostly of then then dont show anymore...neither the image i need.

Comment: i corrected that extra space and it istill dosent work

Comment: Disable the output buffers. I guess there are errors you captured there.

Comment: ok let me see what happens

Comment: aperently theres is an error at line 140, that means my imgttftext() funtion has osomething wrong with it. i istill dont know what it is tough

Comment: @Xmayro updated my answer. imagettftext must be fed by a font path

Answer (score 2):

The methods end up returning the data but you never echo the output.

```
return "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($source);
```

Partially solved:

```
<img src="<?php echo captcha::image(); ?>"/><br>
```

Taken from the comments, next error is font path:

```
self::$font = self::$captcha;
```

Don't set em to the same value. `$font` must point to a font path (like `./arial.ttf`).

Comment: Uff.. well.. you shold rewrite the functions and trace every bit so you know at which position it's not working as expected.

Comment: Annnnnd not solved (:P). Anyway, I'm always confused by the missing semi-colon which don't display a Parse error.

Comment: gues i'll have to watch the tutorial for a third time...or get a easier captcha code.

Comment: @Debflav My workmates don't put the semi-colon, too. PHP should be more strict in those situations so everyone needs to write the `;` ;)

Comment: Yep, it's better to avoid this situation. To my mind, it's a good practice to always put a semi-colon at the end.